# VueJS [Vue warn] Error in render "TypeError" Cannot read property 'PRICE' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to calculate total bill (sum of all product*usage) from an object of  customerProduct data and display the bill amount. I'm calling a computed method to perform this. The customerProduct data is fetched from a `get` api call in the `created()` method.

**Issue:** In the initial render, console shows the following error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRICE' of undefined"`. Is this because the computation is taking some time and meanwhile when the template html code renders, the customerProductData is not fetched properly?
Also, can using `watch` property help here?

Computed method to calculate total bill:

```
computed:{
    billAmount(){
        var billAmountWithoutDiscount = 0;
        if(typeof(this.customerProductData[0].PRICE) == undefined){
            return 0.0
        }
        else{
            for(let i=0;i<this.customerProductData.length;i++){
                billAmountWithoutDiscount += this.customerProductData[i].PRICE * this.customerProductData[i].USAGE;
            }
            return Number((100.0 - this.customerMetaData.discount)*billAmountWithoutDiscount/100).toLocaleString();    
        }   
    } 
}
```

GET api call:

```
 methods:{
    async init(){
        const response = await axios.get("/subscribe/getPresalesPricingMetaData/"+this.customerName)
        this.customerProductData = response.data;
        // console.log(response.data)
        this.getCustomerMetaData();
    },
}
```

customerProduct object:

```
customerProductData:[
0: {
    'PRICE': 10,
    'USAGE': 2000
},
1: {
    'PRICE': 30,
    'USAGE': 230
},
2: {
    'PRICE': 50,
    'USAGE': 200
},
3: {
    'PRICE': 30,
    'USAGE': 1000
},
]
```

The discount value:

```
customerMetaData:{
'discount': 2.2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed that the GET api call was taking time, hence the customerProductData was not getting populated. So when the computed method was called, it did not have any data to work with.

Now if you read the computed method carefully, I actually wrote the code to deal with the above situation using  an `if` statement to return 0 if the customerProductData was not populated. This didn't work because the condition used was incorrect.

```
if(typeof(this.customerProductData[0].PRICE) == undefined)
```

Since, there is no data in customerProductData, the initial access of `this.customerProductData[0]` itself fails, so the `PRICE` property never gets accessed i.e. **not** returning `undefined`

Solution: Check if index 0 exists or not in customerProductData

```
computed:{
    billAmount(){
        var billAmountWithoutDiscount = 0;
        if(!this.customerProductData.hasOwnProperty(0)){
            return 0.0
        }
        else{
            for(let i=0;i<this.customerProductData.length;i++){
                billAmountWithoutDiscount += this.customerProductData[i].PRICE * this.customerProductData[i].CONSUMPTION;
            }
            return Number((100.0 - this.customerMetaData.discount)*billAmountWithoutDiscount/100).toLocaleString();    
        }   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated code. Try once.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   message: "sample mesage",
   customerProductData:[
    {
        'PRICE': 10,
        'USAGE': 2000,
        'CONSUMPTION': 100
    },
    {
        'PRICE': 30,
        'USAGE': 230,
        'CONSUMPTION': 200
    },
    {
        'PRICE': 50,
        'USAGE': 200,
        'CONSUMPTION': 300
    },
    {
        'PRICE': 30,
        'USAGE': 1000,
        'CONSUMPTION': 400
    },
   ],
   customerMetaData: {
    'discount': 2.2
   }
  },
  computed: {
   billAmount(){
          let billAmountWithoutDiscount = 0;
          if(typeof(this.customerProductData[0].PRICE) == undefined){
              return 0.0
          } else {
              for(let i=0;i<this.customerProductData.length;i++){
                  billAmountWithoutDiscount += this.customerProductData[i].PRICE * this.customerProductData[i].CONSUMPTION;
              }
              return Number((100.0 - this.customerMetaData.discount) * billAmountWithoutDiscount / 100).toLocaleString();    
          }   
      }
  },
  methods:{
      async init(){
       let that = this;
          axios.get("/subscribe/getPresalesPricingMetaData/"+this.customerName).then(function(response){
           that.customerProductData = response.data;
           that.getCustomerMetaData();
          })
      },
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <h1>{{ billAmount }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree with your points, corrected the 'USAGE', 'CONSUMPTION' typo in the question. The error still persists, it was not about this key mismatch.

Comment: Could you update the question with latest changes ?. it helps me to debug more

Comment: Yes, did that. Can you please check? 
As I wrote, the customerProductData is getting its data from a GET api call, do you think that time-lag might result in this error?

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187299/discussion-between-vasu-mistry-and-kuncham-vasu).

Answer (score 0):

my first guess is to use method instead of computed

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work, do you want me to show the code for that?

Comment: here is working jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3wcb98Lk/4/ - there were other errors, such as you were trying t get length from object instead of array and also tried to get parameter which wasnt in your object (consumption vs usage)

Comment: That was an error from my side while writing the question. Updated the question with the GET api call too. The error still persists. Could you please check?